# Group by array key

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
{schedules: {team_name: 'Red', color: '#...', due_date '12-12-2018', yards: []} etc
```

I have a function that groups this into an array with the Team Name as the key, which is working fine:

```
setGroupedSchedules(): void {
    let groups = {};
    let schedules = this.schedules;

    for(let schedule of schedules) {
      let teamName = (schedule.team ? schedule.team.name : 'Unassigned');
      groups[teamName] = !groups[teamName] ? [] : groups[teamName];
      groups[teamName].push(schedule);
    }
    this.grouped = groups;
  }
```

How can I also include the team.color for each grouping?

Result:

```
<div style="background:team_color">
Team: Red 
- Schedule 1
 - Yard
 - Yard
- Schedule 2
 - Yard
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the desired result?

Comment: @Romski Have added

Comment: it's a little confusing to present your data in 2 different formats. That aside, I think there is something missing as your input data shows a single object with a `schedule` property, but your function is using an iterable `schedules`.

Comment: @Romski sorry I had the data wrong, it should have been schedules. The grouping function is working fine, I just need the color attribute accessible in the top level of the group

Comment: Still makes no sense. Your code wont run with that input data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
for(let schedule of schedules) {
  let teamName = (schedule.team ? schedule.team.name : 'Unassigned');
  let teamColor = (schedule.team ? schedule.team.color : 'Unassigned');
  groups[teamName] = !groups[teamName] ? [] : groups[teamName];
  colorSchedule = {color: teamColor, team: schedule.team};
  groups[teamName].push(colorSchedule);
}
```

Then the result of the method will be something like

```
{
  "Red": [
    {
      "color": "#...",
      "team": {
        "name": "Red",
        "color": "#...",
        "due_date": "12-12-2018",
        "yards": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Which makes it a little easier for you to see the color of each schedule? I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for since the color and team name are already accessible without running your method at all.

```js
function setGroupedSchedules() {
    let groups = {};
    let schedules = [{team: {name: 'Red', color: '#...', due_date: '12-12-2018', yards: []}}];

    for(let schedule of schedules) {
      let teamName = (schedule.team ? schedule.team.name : 'Unassigned');
      let teamColor = (schedule.team ? schedule.team.color : 'Unassigned');
      groups[teamName] = !groups[teamName] ? [] : groups[teamName];
      colorSchedule = {color: teamColor, team: schedule.team};
      groups[teamName].push(colorSchedule);
    }
    return groups;
}

  console.log(setGroupedSchedules())
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just realised I had the original data incorrect:
{schedule: {team_name: 'Red', color: '#...', due_date '12-12-2018', yards: []} etc